# Protractor + CucumberJS MySQL Query

Tags: asynchronous, cucumber, protractor

Currently my automation framework uses protractor from cucumberJS. We use chai as promised as a assertion library, and I have recently come across a need to do direct mysql queries against a database.

How would I structure a step-definition to be able to get a query, and use the query results within the same step? My current struggles are the asynchronous way protractor is being run, causing me to perform the query after the step requiring the query results happens, and also the scope of which to pass the JSON Object that is created as a result of the query.

```
  this.loginWithMysqlUser = function(uname) {
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user : '*******',
  password : '*******',
  database : '*******'
});

  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM prot_users WHERE username = ?', [uname], function(err, rows) {
    if(err) throw err;

    mysqlUser = {
      username: rows[0].username,
      password: rows[0].password
    };

  });

  connection.end();

    loginpage.login(mysqlUser);

  };
```

This function resides on loginpage declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up containing all of the logic for the login and functions that needed to work with the data within the connection.query function.

Seemed to work ok, and protractor was able to be called from within that query function.

Answer (score 1):

So typically your cucumber test script would like:

```
Feature: As an admin I would like to check if a customer has an     
         account
Scenario: Check that customer name is registered in DB
Given that I am logged in as admin
And I wish to check that customer (foo) is registered
Then I expect following details from DB query:
    | username | password | database |
    | foo      | bar      | mysql    |
```

with step definitions for:

```
Given(/^that I am logged in as admin$/, function(callback){
   ..
   logic goes here
   ..
});
And(/^I wish to check that customer (foo) is registered$/, 
function(username, callback){
   // create connection with db as described
   // with supplied username
   // Use a promise to create mySQL connection
   // and queries DB based on username as described
   // on successful resolution set DBResult to results
   // for username, password and database
   // on error set DBResult to undefined
});
Then(/^I expect following details from DB query$/, function(data,   
callback)
{
   var rows = data.raw;
   // extract values of input table cells into DBExpect using
   // rows[0].username
   // rows[0].password
   // rows[0].database
   // Check equality of DBResult and DBExpect objects
   ..
   expect.isFulfilled(DBResult).toEqual(DBExpect).notify(callback);
});
```